# Tutorials for Wii programming

Tags: homebrew, wii, devkitpro

I have a [Nintendo Wii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii), and I've got [devkitpro](http://www.devkitpro.org/) working to load some simple programs.  The example source code that I've been able to find is very simplistic, such as drawing and rotating a simple shape.

I've been looking for more in depth tutorials, and I haven't been able to find much.  Most of the applications available on [wiibrew](http://www.wiibrew.org) are open source, so I could look through those.  However, I'd rather have something that's a little more geared towards teaching certain techniques, rather than have to browse through someone else's code to find the answer.

What are some good tutorials?  Currently I'm stuck at just getting alpha (translucent) colours to  work, but I'm also interested in getting lighting and other more advanced graphics techniques working.

Comment: Excellent question.  I too am interested, I have a modded Wii, but haven't yet began to put any homebrew apps on...

Comment: Unfortunately wii homebrew is still at a fairly new state, there haven't been a whole lot of tutorials written yet. Another problem too is that a lot of tutorials end up being terrible (badly written, teach poor practices, have bugs, etc)

Comment: Yes, wii homebrew is perfectly legal, there's a port of gcc that can compile wii binaries, and a homebrew library written from scratch. See the devkitpro link in the post. What's not legal is stealing games. They're two unrelated things, but the pirates sometimes try to hide behind homebrew.

Comment: The "console" tag should be changed to "game-console" or something else.  "console" is used for questions about operating system consoles and grouping this with those questions is confusing.

Comment: The bounty makes it look like "150 Tutorials for Wii Programming"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm going to provide you with some nice links:

- <strike>[Getting started](http://www.wii-boss.symbiote.org/files/Programming%20your%20wii-boss.pdf)</strike> (dead)
- <strike>[Wii Programming](http://swik.net/Wii+Programming)</strike> (dead)
- [Wii Wiki about Homebrew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_homebrew)
- [A Blogger who talks about Wii Programming](http://www.codemii.com/category/wii-programming-tutorials/)
- <strike>[A big resource on Wii Development](http://www.wiili.org/index.php/Main_Page)</strike> (dead)

Another very good resource is [WiiBrew](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Main_Page), here are some development specific links:

- [Tutorials](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Tutorials)
- [Debugging](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Debugging)
- [Development Tools](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Development_Tools,)
- [DevkitPro](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/DevkitPro)
- [Getting started with Development](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Development)
- [Developer Tips](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Developer_Tips)

I know you've been to WiiBrew before but it's a very good resource, even if you want to go advanced.
Good luck and have fun programming for Wii! (But please, don't make another Fitness-game ;) )

Comment: That last link, 'Big resource for wii development' is the Wii Linux project, which at the moment is vapourware

Comment: Vapourware means it's a lot of talk, but doesn't actually exist.  The Wii Linux is still very much in the concept stage and can't really be used for anything useful yet.

Comment: It might be soon though, you never know.

Answer (score 3):

What about [this one](http://www.codemii.com/category/wii-programming-tutorials/)? It doesn't go into more advanced stuff, but new tutorials are still being added.

Answer (score 1):

[Gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/) and [DCEmu](http://www.dcemu.co.uk) are 2 great homebrew game dev resources.

Gamedev.net has a lot of great articles, and forums.

DCEmu started as a Dreamcast Emulator website, but it's strong community is probably the current most active for all things game development.

I'm sure you will have a lot of fun reading these websites and their forums, and you will certainly find some tutorials there.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but thought it might be useful to someone else interested in Wii development:

http://unity3d.com/unity/features/wii-publishing

Answer (score 0):

Some friends were programming a game using Wii with Flash. I don't how, though :(

Have you checked this post here? [Writing a game for the Nintendo Wii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466/writing-a-game-for-the-nintendo-wii)